# How to fix "Entity/Field Definitions" issue?

Tags: entities, 9

In Drupal 9 I deleted an image field with the machine name `field_poi_image` and I have a media field with the same machine name. Since then there is an error message in the dashboard.

How can I correct this?

> Entity/Field Definitions Definition of entities and/or fields do not
> match The following changes have been detected in entity type and
> field definitions. Contents The node.field_poi_image field needs to be
> updated.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Devel Entity Updates module, but make sure to back up any database before running  the drush command, in case it works bad.

Comment: @Jaypan Thank you I will try your solution

Comment: @Jaypan I used the module in your comment, to fix the problem in my question. Iml worked, I uninstalled it. I modified another field and I have the same problem, it's really unbearable. It is written that this module should not be used to correct these problems. What's going on with the drupal core?

Comment: Well, this isn't an issue of Drupal core, this happens if/when modules don't manage their config well.

Comment: @Jaypan In my case it is node and image modules